# Callbacks in Java, similar to Javascript

Tags: java, callback

I'm trying to write a callback system in Java that works similar to that of Javascripts, what I'm doing is I'm sending information across the network that has a "callback id" attached to it. When the client receives this data back from the server, it should locate the callback for that id form a collection and call it with the retrieved data.

Here's the current system I've written up while trying to achieve this:

```
public class NetworkCallback {

    private int id;

    private Callable callback;

    public NetworkCallback(Callable callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    public NetworkCallback setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public boolean execute(JSONObject data) {
        try {
            callback.call(); // data?
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

These were stored in a special container a created that would retain index, it's basically just an array with some helper classes. When the client gets information back it will search for the callback and then execute it.

```
void onMessageReceived(byte[] data) {
    JSONObject json = JSONHelper.fromByteArray(data);
    int callbackId = json.getInt("cbid");
    if(callbackId != 0) {
        callbacks.fetch(callbackId).execute(json);
    }
}
```

The issue with this I noticed before even attempting to run the code, pondered for awhile, and ran out of things to think about. The callable class doesn't accept parameters. So, for example, say I wanted to pass a method as a callback like the following:

**psuedo**

```
method(param JSONObject data) {
    print data
}
```

Granted this method isn't going to be the same every time it's called, so it will be created on the fly. An example in javascript of what I'm trying to achieve can be found below:

**Javascript example of what I want**

```
(function caller() {
    called(function(data) {
        console.log("Data: " + data);
    });
})();

function called(callback) {
    callback(Math.random());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You will want to use a [Consumer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) for this. A consumer basically is an object on which you can call `accept(data)`, which executes the callback.

An example:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Consumer consumer = new Consumer() {
            @Override
            public void accept(Object o) {
                System.out.println(o.toString());
            }
        };

        new Test().doSomething("Test", consumer);
    }

    public void doSomething(Object data, Consumer<Object> cb) {
        cb.accept(data);
    }
}
```

This prints "Test" in the console.